# Can't access localhost when I am connected to the internet on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, localhost

As soon as I turn off my WiFi (though I think it would be the case with any internet connection), I can no longer access localhost on Chrome -- no problem on safari.

Specifically, I am trying to access: localhost:9000/#/

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using http://127.0.0.1/ works

Perhaps a better solution exists